# finding item in text file during 2nd read

Tags: python

In the beginning of my program, i opened a file with `f = open("foods.txt", "r+")`. Later I called this method i created

```
def findFood(food):
    foodRegex = re.compile(r'(?P<food>\S+)\s+\-.*')
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
        duplicateFound = re.search(foodRegex, line)
        if duplicateFound.group('food') == food:
            return duplicateFound
        else:
            return False
```

However I run the method again. But my program doesn't work the way I want it to. Specifically

```
def build_meal_plan():
    number_of_items = int(raw_input("How many items would you like to add to your meal plan? "))
    count = 0
    while number_of_items > 0:
        print count
        food = raw_input("Enter in food name: ")
        print food
        if findFood(food):
            servings = int(raw_input("Number of servings: "))
        else:
            print "Food not found! Try again? (y/n): ",
            choice = raw_input()
            if choice == 'y' or choice == "yes":
                number_of_items += 1
            else:
                return
```

However during the 2nd run of my `findFood` method I cannot locate an item i know exists within the `.txt` file. I am not sure why I cannot find the same item I found in the text file during the first run. My assumption is that you can only go through a txt file once.

Comment: Once you call `f.readlines()`, you are at the end of the file. You need to `f.seek(0)` to return to the start. Alternatively, import the file to a list and manipulate that instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe still learning python here. Could you elaborate on "Alternatively, import the file to a list and manipulate that instead"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `f.readlines()`, you are at the end of the file. To return to the start, so you can go through it again, call `f.seek(0)`:

```
def findFood(food):
    foodRegex = re.compile(r'(?P<food>\S+)\s+\-.*')
    for line in f.readlines():
        ...
    f.seek(0)
```

Alternatively, you can import the contents of the file to a list:

```
def import_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return content
```

And use that instead of referring back to the file.

```
def findFood(food, data):
    foodRegex = re.compile(r'(?P<food>\S+)\s+\-.*')
    for line in data:
        ...
```

Then you don't need to worry about returning to the start.